# Iterate through persistentlist hql

Tags: sql, hql

I'm trying iterate through persistantlist in HQL. I have persistanlist and each element of list contains another three object. I need to check if name of this object is eq to value.
Acctualy i have done like this:
`where object.list[0].name = 'value'`
but i want to Iterate list like foreach or something.